Distance of a real number to a discrete set of scaled sine values
Let $M>0$ be an integer, $c\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$ a real number,
$$
a_{m,n}:=\frac{2n}{\pi}\sin\frac{m\pi}{2n},
$$
$$
A_n:=\left\{a_{m,n}:~m=1,\ldots,n-1\right\}, \text{ and}
$$
$$
d_n:=\operatorname{dist}\left(M-\frac{1}{2},A_n\right):=\min_{m=1,..,n-1}\left|M-\frac{1}{2}-a_{m,n}\right|.
$$
Find as small as possible an integer $N=N(M,c)$ such that for all $n\ge N$ it holds that $d_n\ge c$.
Note that the distance $d_n=|M-\frac{1}{2}-a_{p,n}|$ for some $p\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ satisfying
$$
M-1\le a_{p,n}\le M.
$$
Note also that if $\frac{m}{n}$ is sufficiently small then $a_{m,n}\approx m$. So if $\frac{M}{N}$ is sufficiently small then $a_{M,n}\approx M$ and since $a_{M,n}\le M$ we can make $0\le M-a_{M,n}\le \frac{1}{2}-c$ and $d_n=|M-\frac{1}{2}-a_{M,n}|=\frac{1}{2}-(M-a_{M,n})\ge c$.
Guided by the above asymptotic analysis, we can find the following $N$. Note that $\sin x> x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$ for $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. So
$$
M- a_{M,n}\le M-\frac{2n}{\pi}\left(\frac{M\pi}{2n} - \frac{M^3\pi^3}{48n^3}\right).
$$
So to make $M-a_{M,n}\le \frac{1}{2}-c$, it suffices to make
$$
M-\frac{2n}{\pi}\left(\frac{M\pi}{2n} - \frac{M^3\pi^3}{48n^3}\right)\le \frac{1}{2}-c,
$$
that is,
$$
\frac{M^3\pi^2}{24n^2}\le \frac{1}{2}-c.
$$
Solving for $n$ gives
$$
n\ge \sqrt{\frac{M^3\pi^2}{12-24c}}
$$
which can be taken as a feasible $N$. But my key question is to find as small as possible $N$. For example, can we show that the smallest $N$ is of the order
$$
M^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-2c)^{-\frac{1}{2}},
$$
considering $M$ is large and $1-2c>0$ is small?

This is a nice (and well presented) problem. (+1)

If you want to explore tighter bounds, you could try
$$\sin(x) \geq  \pi ^{-\frac{\pi ^2}{3}} x \left(\pi
   ^2-x^2\right)^{\frac{\pi ^2}{6}} \quad  \quad\text{for} \quad x\in (0,\pi)$$ the maximum difference being $0.13$ around $x=2.71$.
Another one is
$$\sin(x) \geq  \frac{x \left(60-7 x^2\right)}{3\left(x^2+20\right)}$$
Edit
From this paper,
$$\sin(x) > x\, \left(\frac{2}{\pi }\right)^{\frac{4x^2}{\pi ^2}}\quad\quad\text{for} \quad x\in \left(0,\frac \pi 2\right)$$ the maximum difference being $0.01$ around $x=1.19$.
This could lead to interesting equations.

Your first inequality is marvelous, may I have a name or source?

@Nuke_Gunray. If my memory is good (who knows ?), I think that I made it more than fifty years ago for a problem in physics. In fact, I think that is could still be improved. I shall try and, if anything comes out, I shall let you know.  Cheers :-)

Thank you very much for your answer. Do you still remember how you found this specifc choice of exponents? They are beautiful.

@Nuke_Gunray. I started from Wallis product; this is sure. Now, the remaining is still fuzzy. If you look at my old posts, you will notice that I have be doing many things with the sine function.

Interesting, I see. I am looking forward to further developements.

@ClaudeLeibovici Thank you so much for the answer! I checked numerically and found it is indeed tighter in order. For the moment, I hope possible more answers will come. Thanks again!

@Nuke_Gunray  Have a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.04430  I did not know it. Very interesting bounds.
